# How to create a property without accessors in Kotlin?

Tags: java, kotlin, accessor

I am using a Kotlin class from Java code. My Kotlin class looks like:

```
class Something {
    var a = 0
}
```

I want to be able to access `a` from Java code like

```
s = new Something();
s.a = 5;
```

however, I only have `s.getA()` and `s.setA(5)`. Is there any way to make this property directly settable and gettable from Java? Obviously we can't have custom getter and setter in this case.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can annotate a property with the [`@JvmField` annotation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-to-kotlin-interop.html#instance-fields) to expose it as a Java field.

> If you need to expose a Kotlin property as a field in Java, you need to annotate it with the @JvmField annotation. The field will have the same visibility as the underlying property. You can annotate a property with @JvmField if it has a backing field, is not private, does not have open, override or const modifiers, and is not a delegated property.

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Thanks!

Comment: This wont work on JVM version >= 1.6.10
`JvmField cannot be applied to a property that overrides some other property`